# SVG - How to get the total no of subpaths in SVGPathElement using Batik libraries?

Tags: svg, path, batik

For example in following case, there are two nested drawings, I want to calculate the area of the larger path and ignore the other.

path        style="opacity:1;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.0343547;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:0"

d="**M** 207.87305 372.2832 L 207.87305 750.23633 L 585.82617 750.23633 L 585.82617 372.2832 L 207.87305 372.2832 z **M** 302.36133 466.77148 L 491.33789 466.77148 L 491.33789 655.74805 L 302.36133 655.74805 L 302.36133 466.77148 z "        transform="matrix(0.9375,0,0,0.9375,0,5.0439605e-6)"        id="path4562" />

Comment: you'd have to iterate through the [pathseglist](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegList) and count up the moves.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Robert. If I need to check about how many path are there, you mean to say we need to check for 'M' and 'Z' to count that.

Comment: You'd count the M or m commands.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's done. How to find the length and area separately for all of these paths individually ?

Comment: Using the [DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#DOMInterfaces) although there's no area calculation there so you'll have to work it out from first principles I guess. Length should be doable though.

Comment: I am using the Batik library for Java which provides the APIs for evaluating the total length, but can not find any API for finding the length for individual paths in this case. API Reference:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength

Comment: Start at 0, increase by some delta. Call getPathSegAtLength(), when the path segment changes index, check what segment type is at that index, if it's another M or m then that's the length. Repeat till you run off the end of the path.